# Upload Spring Project to github account with/without server and how do I embed mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, github

Please I intend to upload a small spring application I built to my git account. It uses tomcat server. What I don't know is that does the convention mandate that I upload my project together with the server or i upload the project alone and a person who intends to view the application downloads it and downloads his/her own server to be able to use the application? Here is an image file structure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxuBY.png)

And another issue is this application makes use of a database I created using mySQL workbench. How do I now make this upload together with my database?

Answer (score 0):

Basically if it is a pure Java / Spring application the one using it / downloading it must setup the application server and the database server. If you need any init scripts for your database you can add them to your project (e.g. SQL Scripts).

If you want everything to work out of the box, without requiring one to setup a database server and an application server, you should have a look at spring boot (ships with an embedded tomcat) and may use an embedded database like HSQL or SQLite.

Hope I could help